# ObjectEncoderOutputStream Out Of Memory Exception possible?

Tags: java, netty

I noticed that [`ObjectEncoderOutputStream`](https://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.1/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/serialization/ObjectEncoderOutputStream.html) uses `ObjectOutputStream`. Traditionally `ObjectOutputStream` can cause an OOME if it's not reset on a regular basis. Is `ObjectEncoderOutputStream` susceptible to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, the `ObjectEncoderOutputStream` is not susceptible to the same problem, because of the way it uses the `ObjectOutputStream`.

For each `writeObject` call a *new* `ObjectOutputStream` (specifically a `CompactObjectOutputStream`) is created to write that single object and then it is closed again.

Thus, no `ObjectOutputStream` ever holds on to old references and thus doesn't cause a OOM this way.